# Selecting Excel chart template according to formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, charts

While trying to streamline a part of a reporting job, I encountered a problem.
My aim is to represent the answer to several questions through the appropriate chart template for each of them. Let's say I have two types of question ("Do-you-like" questions and "How-many" questions), and for each one I've already created its specific chart template.
My worksheet is formatted roughly like this:

[worksheet example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lh0eT.jpg)

Everything else is automated, and the chart is already placed and spaced in the correct position: I just wish that Excel could select the template "Do you like.crtx" for the graph in F2 if the text in C2 is "Do you like", and conversely select the template "How many.crtx" for the graph in F2 if the text in C2 is "How many".

I think this is doable through VBA and found some results in this regard, but since I'm quite new to VBA and the file will have to be opened and used by people who know just the basics of Excel, my question is: is there a way to do this without VBA, just using formulas and/or chart properties?

Thanks to everybody in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There is Survey sheet in Excel, you can refer to this support article:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/surveys-in-excel-hosted-on-the-web-5fafd054-19f8-474c-97ec-b606fcda0ff9

Comment: Maybe my question was not entirely clear, but I don't need help with the surveying: I need to teach Excel to select the right chart template for my question. The survey is done in other softwares (and it should remain like this).
Does the Survey sheet in Excel allow to automate the chart template pick?